# Using Custom External Fonts with ModernCV

Tags: xetex, moderncv

Is there anyway to redefine the fonts used in `moderncv` from an external font file? (I will be using XeLaTeX).

This is code I have seen use it, but not sure how to redefine the values in `moderncv` (I am using the banking theme) to change name, headers, etc.

```
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Hai}\selectfont #1 % First name font
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\selectfont #2 % Last name font
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In moderncv, fonts are defined by these

```
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{34}{36}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\LARGE\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\large\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\hintfont}{}
```

You can simply define newfontfamily like

```
\usepackage{fontspec} %loads fontspec
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,
             Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\bio[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Biolinum} 
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Corbel} 
\newfontfamily\calibri[Ligatures=TeX]{Calibri} 
\newfontfamily\arial[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial} 
\newfontfamily\mytimes[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
```

and then use them.

```
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\calibri\fontsize{34}{36}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\mytimes\LARGE\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\bio\small\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\calibri\large\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\arial\Large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\arial\large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\hintfont}{}
```

I have randomly chosen the fonts. Choose yours as you wish.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[black]{banking}

\usepackage[scale=0.75, top=20mm, bottom=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec} %loads fontspec
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,
             Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\bio[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Biolinum} 
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Corbel} 
\newfontfamily\calibri[Ligatures=TeX]{Calibri} 
\newfontfamily\arial[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial} 
\newfontfamily\mytimes[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}


\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\calibri\fontsize{34}{36}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\mytimes\LARGE\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\bio\small\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\calibri\large\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\arial\Large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\arial\large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\hintfont}{}

% personal data
\firstname{Jane}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Title Here}               % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\address{City}{State}    % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\mobile{(123) 456 7890}                    % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\phone{3654789}
\fax{85698745}
\email{janedoe@gmail.com} 
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
\extrainfo{\textbf{bla bla}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{some section}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just found that `\usepackage{fontspec}` is not necessary. Moreover, `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}` gives **Option clash** error. (Of course I switched the compiler to LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX.)

Comment: What's the command that needs to be overridden for the main document font?